# What does WITH do in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I can't understand this example from the [doc](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-with.html):

```
START david=node(1)
MATCH david--otherPerson-->()
WITH otherPerson, count(*) as foaf
WHERE foaf > 1
RETURN otherPerson
```

What does otherPerson and count(*) do in the WITH line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you see here are two queries joined by with.
With acts as a return for the first query and as "start" of the second one.
It set's the part of the context that is passed on.

```
normally you would have
START david=node(1)
MATCH david--otherPerson-->()
RETURN otherPerson, count(*) as foaf
```

and then do the filtering in your calling code.

with with you can just start the next query directly in cypher, which can only see what is declared in the with section, 
in this case: otherPerson and foaf the other identifiers and data of the first query are no longer available.